# Annotations for types.FunctionType

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I need some sort of annotation that works similarly to `typing.Callable[[args, ..], ret]`, but is more strict regarding allowed input. `Callable` just requires that an instance has a proper `__call__()` interface (see [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cc12c965af16550bb1af32e0485217ae6d718218/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L508)). I need a type hint that would require a `types.FunctionType` with a proper `__call__()` interface. Sadly there is no such thing like `typing.FunctionType`.

What have I tried?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from types import FunctionType


_T1 = TypeVar("_T1")
_T2 = TypeVar("_T2")


class AnnotatedFunctionType(FunctionType, Generic[_T1, _T2]):
    def __call__(self, *args: _T1) -> _T2:
        pass
```

Fails (of course!) with an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

```py
from typing import Union, Callable
from types import FunctionType

AnnotatedFunctionType = Union[Callable, FunctionType]
```

Too broad, can't use `AnnotatedFunctionType[[arg1, arg2, ...], ret]`.

```py
from typing import Union, Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec
from types import FunctionType

_T = TypeVar("_T")
_P = ParamSpec("_P")
AnnotatedFunctionType = Union[Callable[_P, _T], FunctionType]
```

It works, but it isn't strict. This allows for any function or a callable with a specified structure. Also it doesn't work with multiple arguments when scanning with mypy.

My guess is that in order to do what I want, I would need to write a Protocol class with every function attribute, that I need. It does allow types that are different than `FunctionType`, but it would work. If [python/typing#213](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) was ever finalized, I guess that I could to something like `Intersection[FunctionTypeProtocol[_T1, _T2], FunctionType]` or `FunctionTypeProtocol[_T1, T2] & FunctionType`.

What approach would accomplish what I want (and it would work static type analysis tools like mypy)? It's fine if it requires some external package.

Comment: This sounds extremely XY-ish. Why do you want to enforce this? Why do you require that your users pass a `def` function but not some other callable (class with `__call__`, for example)?

Comment: If you need some function-specific dunders like `__code__`, just use a protocol to require such (and you already list this as possible solution). What requirements does this fail to satisfy? When answering this question, remember that python uses "duck typing", and so a class with `__code__`, `__defaults__`, `__globals__` and `__call__`  (did I forget anything?) is fully functionally equivalent to a `def` function.

Comment: @STerliakov For introspection-heavy code, checking that an input is a `types.FunctionType` is useful due to many callables which aren't functions; signature inspection is likely to yield surprising results if something is a `types.MethodType` (e.g. decorated with `@classmethod`), common callable attributes aren't available on `@property`-decorated function definitions (even though mypy thinks these are `Callable`), `inspect.getsource` can't be called on `functools.partial` objects, and you certainly don't want to use an object defined with `__call__` if you only want to handle functions.

Comment: That being said, mypy doesn't detect functions as `types.FunctionType` objects at all, so @oBrstisf8o unless you have a more fleshed out example (involving where you want to see `AnnotatedFunctionType` show a warning), it is unlikely any naiive solution would work with mypy.

Comment: @dROOOze Introspection-heavy code is unlikely to be well-typed, it usually relies on some internal details and has to deal with lots of typing errors (in my own experience - sufficient to just abandon typing on such projects, where you find yourself constantly fighting `mypy` errors).

Comment: @STerliakov In my experience, part of that difficulty is due to lack of differentiation between `types.FunctionType`, `types.MethodType`, `property`, etc. in mypy :). I've hardly ever had typing difficulties with introspecting `class` objects, for example, as they're much better supported.

Comment: @STerliakov Yes, from all of the alternatives I've currently found, protocol is closest to what I want, (and yes, you forgot to list, for example ``__get__``, which in this case I need), For this reason ``@classmethod`` and ``@staticmethod`` -decorated functions would not work with my (currently not annotated) code, but they also implement ``__get__`` (with I think have the same? function interface), so they would pass static analysis checks without errors nor warnings. It just surprises me that there is no sensible for this seemingly (at least for me) use-case.

Comment: Well, this is the first time I meet such requirement (never raised in mypy issue tracker too, if I'm looking up right words), so it's likely very rare. There are lot of missing features with much higher priority (to name a few - arbitrary arguments modification or at least addition, hot `mypy` bugs like asymmetric properties mistreatment, union vs join during inference, Intersection type), so your feature may come into reality at some point, but it's unlikely to happen soon. Also, since it can be resolved with `Intersection`, I suspect such FR will be closed in favor of `Intersection` FR.

Comment: [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) supports `Intersection` types - maybe it's worth a try in your case.

Comment: Indeed, ``basedmypy`` looks interesting.

Comment: @STerliakov I've done some digging and it turned out, that for my use-case, the theoretical solution using ``Intersection`` won't work before [python/mypy#13337](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13337) won't be resolved.